# Транслятор выражений в ассемблер проблема IO и архитектура

Tags: c++

Хочу создать небольшой транслятор выражений в ассемблер. Написал такой код, который работает для выражений типа 2+2:

`io_error.h:`

```
#ifndef IO_ERROR_H
#define IO_ERROR_H

#include <string>

namespace io
{
    // Read new character from input stream
    void getch();

    // Return current character
    char look();

    // Output a string with tab
    void __emit(std::string const& s);

    // Output a string with tab and CRLF
    void emitln(std::string const& s);

    // Get a number from input stream
    char getnum();

    // Report error
    void error(std::string const& s);

    // Report error and quit
    void abort(std::string const& s);

    // Report what was expected
    void expected(std::string const& s);

    //Match a specific input character
    bool match(char c);
}


#endif // IO_ERROR_H
```

`io_error.cpp`:

```
#include "io_error.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

namespace io
{
    static char symbol = 0;

    // Read new character from input stream
    void getch()
    {
        std::cin >> symbol;
    }

    // Return current character
    char look()
    {
        return symbol;
    }

    // Report error
    void error(std::string const& s)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << s << std::endl;
    }

    // Report error and quit
    void abort(std::string const& s)
    {
        error(s);
        std::exit(0);
    }

    // Report what was expected
    void expected(std::string const& s)
    {
        abort(s);
    }

    //Match a specific input character
    bool match(char c)
    {
        if (symbol != c)
        {
            expected("" + c);
        }
        return symbol == c;
    }

    // Output a string with tab
    void __emit(std::string const& s)
    {
        std::cout << "\t" << s;
    }

    // Output a string with tab and CRLF
    void emitln(std::string const& s)
    {
        __emit(s);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    char getnum()
    {
        if (!std::isdigit(symbol)) expected("Integer");
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

`translator.h`:

```
#ifndef TRANSLATOR_H
#define TRANSLATOR_H

void term();
void expression();

#endif // TRANSLATOR_H
```

`translator.cpp`:

```
#include "io_error.h"
#include "translator.h"

void term()
{
    io::emitln(std::string("mov eax, ") + io:: getnum());
}

// Recognize and translate an Add
void add()
{
    io::match('+');
    io::getch();
    term();
    io::emitln("add eax, ebx");
}

// Recognize and translate a Subtract
void subtract()
{
    io::match('-');
    term();
    io::emitln("sub eax, ebx");
}

void expression()
{
    term();
    io::emitln("mov ebx, eax");
    io::getch();
    switch (io::look())
    {
        case '+': add(); break;
        case '-': subtract(); break;
    }
}
```

`main:`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    io::getch();
    expression();

    return a.exec();
}
```

У меня много проблем с этим кодом.

1) Реализация ввода/вывода и ошибок: операции, которые должны быть простыми, на деле выполняют больше, чем обещает название: например, читают следующий символ. Это вносит путаницу при отладке

2) Код процедурный. Не знаю, плохо ли это, но обычно даже системный софт пишут в парадигме ООП. Какие здесь можно выделить сущности? Абстрагировать ввод/вывод, сделать обработку ошибок через исключения, создать класс транслятора?

3) Вообще, система ввода/вывода здесь очень грязная. Как лучше реализовать чтение выражений с консоли, чтобы операции ввода/вывода были простыми, выполняли одно действие, позволяли парсить выражение транслятором и делать другие вещи, которые я еще не пробовал реализовать?

Comment: Почитайте какие-нибудь книжки про построение компиляторов (книга дракона - Компиляторы. Принципы, технологии, инструменты например).

Comment: @VTT, я пытаюсь написать транслятор по циклу статей. Интересует именно архитектура приложения. Погружаться в дебри синтаксических деревьев времени особо нет.

Comment: Тогда вам хватит второй главы из той книги - "Простой cинтаксически управляемый транслятор"